# execute two procedure using one event

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures

```
CREATE EVENT EVENT_NOTIFICATION
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-10-15 15:42:00'
COMMENT 'Insert Notification'
DO CALL
sp_Notification();
SP_notificationStatus();
```

i want to execute above two procedure 'sp_Notification' and 'SP_notificationStatus' one after another but only 'sp_Notification' procedure is executing.

How to execute 2 procedure using one event?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want this:

```
CREATE EVENT EVENT_NOTIFICATION
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-10-15 15:42:00'
COMMENT 'Insert Notification'
DO CALL
sp_Notification();

CREATE EVENT EVENT_NOTIFICATION
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-10-15 15:42:00'
COMMENT 'Insert Notification'
DO CALL
SP_notificationStatus();
```

You can also make a new procedure that calls both of them, then schedule that once.

Comment: i want to execute above 2 procedure using single event

Comment: See my note at the end then.

Make a new procedure that calls the other two, and call that for your event.

Comment: didn't see your last note until i put the same solution in my answer. good solution. especially when the second procedure is dependent on the first

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration runs the two stored procedures:

```sql
/*!50106 set global event_scheduler = 1*/;

/*Table structure for table `notification` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `notification`;

CREATE TABLE `notification` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mydate` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/*Table structure for table `notificationStatus` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `notificationStatus`;

CREATE TABLE `notificationStatus` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mydate` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

/* Event structure for event `EVENT_NOTIFICATION` */

/*!50106 DROP EVENT IF EXISTS `EVENT_NOTIFICATION`*/;

DELIMITER $$

/*!50106 CREATE EVENT `EVENT_NOTIFICATION` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
           STARTS '2013-10-12 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
BEGIN
    CALL `sp_Notification`();
    CALL `sp_notificationStatus`();
END */$$

DELIMITER ;

/* Procedure structure for procedure `sp_Notification` */

/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `sp_Notification` */;

DELIMITER $$

/*!50003 CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Notification`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `notification` (`mydate`) VALUES (NOW());
END */$$

DELIMITER ;

/* Procedure structure for procedure `sp_notificationStatus` */

/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `sp_notificationStatus` */;

DELIMITER $$

/*!50003 CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_notificationStatus`()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `notificationStatus` (`mydate`) VALUES (NOW());
END */$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT EVENT_NOTIFICATION
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-10-15 15:42:00'
COMMENT 'Insert Notification' DO
 BEGIN
  CALL sp_Notification();
  CALL SP_notificationStatus();
 END //

Answer (score 0):

I have run into same problem, the second procedure was called immediately, and here is the answer:

```
DELIMITER //                     -- THIS IS IMPORTANT!!!!
CREATE EVENT EVENT_NOTIFICATION
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 DAY 
  STARTS '2013-10-15 15:42:00'
COMMENT 'Insert Notification'
DO
BEGIN
  CALL sp_Notification();        -- Otherwise you event will end HERE after ;
  CALL SP_notificationStatus();
END;
END //                           -- Set delimiter back to ';'
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above didn't work for me when i had a similar problem.

I solved it by creating a new stored procedure that included the procedures needed in the event.

**example**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
BEGIN
   sp_Notification();
   SP_notificationStatus();
END
```

**and in the event**

```
CREATE EVENT EVENT_NOTIFICATION
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-10-15 15:42:00'
COMMENT 'Insert Notification'
DO 
  CALL new_procedure();
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a `CALL` statement:

```
CREATE EVENT EVENT_NOTIFICATION
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2013-10-15 15:42:00'
COMMENT 'Insert Notification'
DO 
 BEGIN
  CALL sp_Notification();
  CALL SP_notificationStatus();
 END;
```

Comment: That won't work.

First it will create an event, then it will call the second procedure immediately.

Comment: Oops, now it will with the BEGIN/END enclosure. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think by using the following approach you can able to execute multiple procedure in a one event

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT Raju_RemoveExpiredItemsEvent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY

DO
  BEGIN
        CALL Raju_DeleteExpiredItems('comments');
        CALL Raju_DeleteExpiredItems('likes');
        END$$

DELIMITER ;
```