# mysql event not running, scheduler is ON

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql Event based on this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41099947/9478434

My Event is:

```
DELIMITER $$                    
CREATE 
DEFINER=`db_admin`@`%`
EVENT dbname.my_event
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 DAY 
  STARTS '2018-05-30 22:58:00'
COMMENT 'Do Archive old posts'
DO
BEGIN
  CALL stored_procedure_1();       
  CALL stored_procedure_2();
END;
END $$                          
DELIMITER ;
```

But it does not run at the time it should run. I checked the `event_scheduler` variable and it is `ON` and in the `processlist` there is a record with Command: `Sleep`.

Comment: `EVERY 1 DAY 
  STARTS '2018-05-30 22:58:00'` looks like the event wil run on `2018-05-31 22:58:00` again.

Comment: It was added before that time and it did not work.

Comment: Did you check the information_schema database and Event table to verify the vent was created?

Comment: `show events from db_name` shows the event exists